# Print .docx without Pages.app

Tags: macos, pages, ms-office, quicklook

Sometimes I simply want to print Microsoft Word documents. If I view them in Quick Look, they display as I would like to print them. However, when I try to print them from the Finder, it opens Pages.app and the rendering is significantly different.

Is there anyway to print the document as Quick Look renders it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open Word documents with the built-in TextEdit app.

It will display and print them the same way (as far as I can tell) as QuickLook does.

Comment: So it does. I was thrown by the fact that QuickLook doesn't show page breaks.